# How do you globally change the search placeholder text for SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, modern-experience, custom, sharepoint-search

For SharePoint Online, I'm looking for a way to globally change the search input placeholder text shown in the attached screenshot.

Is this possible without having to add a JavaScript web-part on every single page?

[image: SharePoint online site search]

I have tried messing with "Site Settings --> Search Settings" before, but when I change those settings it seems to only change the "admin" search input which appears to be an entirely different search component with a dropdown(2nd screenshot).

[image: SharePoint online search settings]

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It isn't possible without deploying something to each site. In addition, the search bar will be moving to the SuiteNav, I believe scheduled for end of this month. As for anything in the SuiteNav, it should not be overridden with custom CSS.

Comment: the site search bar is going to be put inside the SuiteNav? Isn't that the "waffle menu" in the top left for all office programs? Seems odd to move Sharepoint site search to that location

Comment: SuiteNav is the entire bar at the top of the screen; it will be moved into the middle of that bar.

Comment: Is there a changelog or feature release for Sharepoint Online somewhere that would be tracking these types of changes?

Comment: Yes, see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=34273 for this specific change. You can filter/search on other items.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an OOTB way to achieve your requirement.

As a workaround, you could add JavaScript/jQuery code by [react script editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) in all the modern pages.

Or you could create an Application Customizer solution to inject custom JavaScript code to acheive it.The following blog for your reference.

[Step By Step Procedure To Add A JS File To All Pages In A SPFx Modern Pages Using SharePoint Framework Extension](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedure-to-add-a-js-file-to-all-pages-in-a-spfx-modern-pages-using-sharepoint-framework-extension/)

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to change the search placeholder text for a specific (sub) site or an entire site collection using PnP PowerShell.

Example:

```
Set-PnPSearchSettings -Scope Site -SearchBoxPlaceholderText "My custom search placeholder"
```

You can find the detailed steps at: [SharePoint Online: How to change the placeholder text in the search box](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-online-how-to-change-the-placeholder-text-in-the-search-box/)